# How to send a POST API request in Apache NIFi

Tags: json, rest, http, apache-nifi

I have NiFi pipeline which get data from a CSV and transform into a JSON. Then I want to send a post API request from the JSIN created.
I need help setting up the InvokeHTTP processor in NiFi. 
API authorization is using an API key. I need assistance of how to define the API keys, URL and JSON body inside InvokeHTTP processor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the API is like most well-formed APIs, all you would need to do is make sure the JSON is in the flowfile body and then add a flowfile attribute for the authentication header expected by the API. Put the API key in the attribute, and there is a field in `InvokeHttp` that allows you to specify a regex of which flowfile attributes are to be sent as headers.